# Docker: Error when executing command docker exec my_container composer php yii migrate --interactive=0

Tags: php, docker-compose

I'm working on a project in Yii2 running under a VM in Docker on a Mac with Sierra Os. 
While I execute the migrtion command which is this one:

```
docker exec my_container composer PHP Yii migrate --interactive=0enter
```

I receive this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
Command "php" is not defined.
```

I have Google that online but I have not found any good solutions. 
I really hope to find a solution to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Am not entirely sure what `composer PHP Yii migrate` is, but docs at docker says

> COMMAND should be an executable, a chained or a quoted command will
>   not work.

Maybe [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#extended-description) can help you.

Comment: This command is used for migrating the table when you are installing a project base on Yii framework. In this case, it is using composer to install the dependencies. I need to understand why the PHP command is not defined and what causes that issue.   In a Windows machine, it is working on my Mac no. In the instructions for this project I read this:
Run the migrations
You will need to create your database scheme. The application comes with migrations ready to use. In order to run them, execute the following command:
`docker exec container_1 php yii migrate --interactive=0`

Answer (score 0):

The command you want is:

`docker exec {container_name} php ./{console/}yii migrate --interactive=0 [ENTER]`

Case sensitive.

Composer is should be run as a separate command as it does something different from executing migrations.

The {console} is if you have the advanced application template.